# Azure Cosmos DB Token Let's Me Hit Endpoint, but Isn't Authenticated

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, access-control

I'm using this code to generate my token. I've just barely changed the sample code for token generation to also return the date to me because I have to send that in the request.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var inputKey = "my-key-from-azure"; // Have tried both primary and secondary master keys from cosmos db

var today = new Date().toUTCString();

console.log(today);

console.log(getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey("POST", "dbs", "dbs/ToDoList", today, inputKey))

function getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, resourceType, resourceId, date, masterKey) 
{  
  var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");  

  var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
       (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
       (resourceId || "") + "\n" +   
       date.toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
       "" + "\n";  

  var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");  
  var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");  

  var MasterToken = "master";  

  var TokenVersion = "1.0";  

  return encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);  
}
```

Here are the request headers. For the x-ms-date, my DB was created after this, the latest version, so I assume it uses this version; can I verify this somehow?

```
{
  Authorization: [my-auth-string],
  x-ms-version: "2017-02-22",
  x-ms-date: "Fri, 05 Oct 2018 19:06:17 GMT",
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

But I'm getting back an error message that is complaining about the validity of my token.

```
{
  "code": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'post\nsprocs\ndbs/metrics/colls/LoungeVisits/sprocs/calculateAverage\nfri, 05 oct 2018 19:06:17 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 41cd36af-ad0e-40c3-84c8-761ebd14bf6d, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0"
}
```

The payload *was* built according to the expected protocol, as far as I can tell from the docs.

[Execute a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/execute-a-stored-procedure), [Common Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers), [Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN). The request is sent using postman, and I'm copying the values my script generates directly into it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cosmos DB has two types of 'keys'.

[Master keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#master-keys) - Used for administrative resources: database accounts, databases, users, and permissions
[Resource tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens) - Used for application resources: containers, documents, attachments, stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs

[Securing access to Azure Cosmos DB data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data)

The examples you are providing do not match the examples from the documentation, such as: [Code sample to use a master key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#code-sample-to-use-a-master-key)

As for using tokens:

> You can use a resource token (by creating Cosmos DB users and permissions) when you want to provide access to resources in your Cosmos DB account to a client that cannot be trusted with the master key.

And I am not seeing the the following `var TokenVersion = "1.0"` needed to be used with Master Tokens, etc.

Comment: So I'm looking at my own user page, which must have access to our Cosmos DB because I wrote the stored procedure in the portal. Where can I find my resource tokens so I can run a script with them to access? And are you saying I should or should not be using `var TokenVersion = "1.0"`, because my code currently is. That's what the doc page had said to use.